# interactivity between RAM and CPU

Tags: cpu

I have a very silly question, when data is transferred from the RAM to the CPU is this data transferred "copies" of the original data stored inside the RAM?

Comment: To get the whole picture, they are transfered thru the BUS a set of wires that hold either 0 or 1 for each bit of data, and are connected to the Central Processing Unit where instructions at the machine language level get executed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's reasonable to consider that as a copy of the data in the RAM.  It's a copy in the sense that if you modify the data in the CPU, the data in RAM remains unchanged.

(But at the end of the day it doesn't really matter what you call it: the computer is going to do what it does, regardless of what words you use to describe it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess you could say that as if you change data in CPU, even then, the data in RAM will be same.(IF it has not been erased due to some reason)

Comment: `IF it has not been erased due to some reason` like [destructive read-out](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectric_RAM#Description) (immediately followed by a write-back unless part of a read-"modify"-write operation where the data written to a cell is supplied externally) (I guess you could call that two copies with the original gone).

Comment: (Oops - I guess I have to read up on contemporary 1T DRAM - need for refresh, but non-destructive reads, does that mean *no write-back*?)